# C++ - string.replace not working

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2010, replace

I am looking through some examples and I cannot seems to see why the string replace function is not working.  I am using Visual C++ 2010

the line of code I am trying to compile is:

```
string MyClass::replacestr (const string &input){

    string subString = "str";
    string subString2 = "STR";

    for(int index = input.find(subString);    index != string::npos;  index = input.find(subString, index +subString.length()))
    {
        input.replace(index, 2, subString2);
    }   

}
```

It gives me this error in visual studio:

```
3   IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "std::basic_string<_Elem, _Traits, _Ax>::replace [with _Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>, _Ax=std::allocator<char>]" matches the argument list and object (the object has type qualifiers that prevent a match)   c:\..test.cpp   36  Test
```

I just don't understand why it wont work the way it si explained in the c++ refernce website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

string replace changes the contents of the string. Your string is marked as const. That means you can't call replace on it.

Comment: Jesus, it has been a long day.  Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

Replace modifies the contents of the string (is non const member function). You are passing a **`const`** reference to the function. That's why replace is giving you errors.

**You can not call a non const member function on a const object.**

---

The error message could have been much clearer though.